# How to use rss feeds as Blog post and its topic in umbraco

Tags: rss, umbraco, blogs, rss-reader

I would like to have Blog post of the RSS feeds of a particular URL, whenever any new topic will be added to the RSS, a new blog post should automatically be created.

I would like to have it in Umbraco.

Does anyone have any workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this will require a scheduled service of some kind there is one option if you would like to use Umbraco only which is to use Umbraco Scheduled Tasks

Read more at http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/scheduled-tasks, there is also the http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/taskscheduler that brings a bit more power to scheduled tasks in Umbraco.

Depending on your Umbraco-version (which you didn't state) the page (blog) creation can vary, here is however a pretty nice sample http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Samples_and_Articles/Creating_umbraco_pages_programmatically

So the process would be

1. Create an aspx page will the required logic to work with your RSS-feeds
2. When a new post in a RSS-feed is detected invoke the code that creates a new page/blog